# Angular 14 Access Route Config Title Property in Component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to read the title out of the `route.snapshot.data` of the routeConfig in Angular 14?  I can see it in the `route.snapshot.data` as a [Symbol](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14.0.4/packages/router/src/operators/resolve_data.ts#L24), but can't seem to access it:

```
{
  path: 'example',
  title: 'Title of Page',
  component: ExamplePage
}
```

```
this.route.snapshot.data[Symbol('RouteTitle')]) // undefined
console.log(this.route.snapshot.data) // { Symbol('RouteTitle'): 'Title of Page' }
```

I'm using the TitleStrategy to update the title to be:

```
${title} | ${companyName}`
```

But want to get the pre-strategy title in the component for use in the page so they match without using the `Title` service to `getTitle` and slicing the `companyName` off each time.

Comment: Symbol('RouteTitle')] would be between "" I believe

Comment: @Drenai that's an Angular thing as of v14 when they provided the new title property in the route config.  Looks like the `route.snapshot.data` gets populated with it using `Symbol('RouteTitle')` as the key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the `title` from the [`snapshot.routeConfig`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#routeConfig), it returns a [`Route`](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) that contains the snapshots [`title`](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#title):

```json
{
  path: 'example',
  title: 'Title of Page',
  component: ExamplePage
}
```

```js
@Component({/* Configuration */})
export class ExamplePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.routeConfig?.title);
    // Output: Title of Page
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was overly focused on `snapshot.data` since I could see the object literal had the title using `Symbol(RouteTitle)` in the `console.log` output, and didn't jump elsewhere in the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

I was just experiencing this very same problem in Angular 14, made especially more complicated because I am using a "title resolver" on one of my routes, in order to create a dynamic title for each post page.

It turns out the way to retrieve the title is through "TitleStrategy", which has a method called "getResolvedTitleForRoute". (See [the Angular page for TitleStrategy for more info](https://angular.io/api/router/TitleStrategy))

Here's how I achieved it in my **app.component.ts** file (I am including more than you need, probably, but I find that context can be helpful :-) ):

```
import { Component, Inject, Renderer2, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router, RouterState, TitleStrategy } from '@angular/router';


declare const gtag: Function; // <------------Important: the declaration for gtag is required!

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My Generic App Title';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private titleStrategy: TitleStrategy,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
      if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        this.injectScripts();
        this.handleRouteEvents();
      }
  }

  injectScripts() {
     // Injects a Google Tag Manager script
  }

  handleRouteEvents() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const p_path = event.urlAfterRedirects;
        const p_location = this._document.location.href;
        const p_title = this.getTitle(this.router.routerState, this.router.routerState.root).join('-').trim();
        console.log('p_title: |', p_title, '|');
        console.log('p_path: ', p_path);
        console.log('p_location: ', p_location);
        gtag('event', 'page_view', { 
          'page_title': p_title ? p_title : p_path,
          'page_path': p_path,
          'page_location': p_location
        });
      }
    });

  }

  getTitle(state: RouterState, parent: ActivatedRoute): string[] {
    const data = [];
    
    if (parent && parent.snapshot && this.titleStrategy.getResolvedTitleForRoute(parent.snapshot)) {
      data.push(this.titleStrategy.getResolvedTitleForRoute(parent.snapshot));
    }
    if (state && parent && parent.firstChild) {
      data.push(...this.getTitle(state, parent.firstChild));
    }
    return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a case where I still need to use `title.setTitle('Foo');` so that my browser tab's text shows the name of my app when a user is logging in (kind of like a default title until they go to an actual page).

As such, I'm not able to retrieve the current route's title with the above or with `title.getTitle();`.

For me, I had to inject Angular's `Router` and then do the following (Angular 14):

`const routeTitle: string = this.router.config.find((route: Route): boolean => route.path.includes(url))?.title as string;`

Where `url` comes from the `url` property of `RouterEvent`.