# How does Firebase Analytics track screen views / users in a mobile app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, capacitor

I'm looking at including Firebase Analytics in a project to help get some better understanding about how users are consuming the various parts of my mobile app.

Much like with Google Analytics and tracking page titles, it appears that Firebase Analytics will automatically track screen views based on this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews). Am I understanding this correctly?

My project uses capacitor, and it appears that there are a few plugins out there already to help with this. Do you manually need `setScreenName` within each view of your app, or will Firebase automatically send back the screen name to Firebase once all configured within your project?

Also, with tracking a user id, do you just need to `setUserId` once in the app, or with each view that is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

> Much like with Google Analytics and tracking page titles, it appears that Firebase Analytics will automatically track screen views based on this doc. Am I understanding this correctly?

Yes, that's true, but on Android and iOS that only applies to native views and not the webview.

> Do you manually need `setScreenName` within each view of your app, or will Firebase automatically send back the screen name to Firebase once all configured within your project?

Yes, you need to call `setScreenName` manually for each page. You can, of course, create a central listener that gets the current page name when you navigate and calls the Capacitor Firebase Analytics plugin.

> Also, with tracking a user id, do you just need to `setUserId` once in the app, or with each view that is displayed?

You need to call `setUserId` once.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If we are using the webview in our app, does that mean we need to Disable Screenview Tracking via `FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled` within each app?

Comment: You don't have to disable it, but no meaningful data is collected, only the screen name of the webview when starting the app.

Comment: Again, appreciate the info. It's very helpful. Do you have any suggestions on how to get the current page name from a central listener? I'm using Angular in my capacitor project and it appears that we can get the URL when the listening to the route change, but that does not give some good details around what the page title is.

Comment: You can get the current title from the route snapshot (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72834889/6731412) every time a route navigation ends.